# Google web app script doget() do not return any webpage after rendering/evaluating more than twice

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, rendering

This is the link of my web app:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzmbR9ljp7d5T8vsPTKt4b_v461NDNtxh6w6s1FFuJOhSGh6EKE/exec?view=home

> 1. Step1) at home page -> OK

[image]

> 2. Step2) click enter-> OK

[image]

> 3. Step3) click add weekly -> **Renders nothing**

[image]
>

> Here is the LOG:

[image]

> Well, weirdly, if I manually input the url paremeters, the page is rendered just fine:

[image]

> here is the code snippet of doget():

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(e);
  Logger.log("view="+e.parameters.view);

  if(e.parameters.view =="weekly"){
    Logger.log("view==weekly");

    var page = addWeeklyReport();

    //Logger.log(page.getTitle());
    //return page.evaluate();

    return page.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }else if(e.parameters.view == "home"){
    Logger.log("view is home");
    var home = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("homehs");
    return home.evaluate();
  //return addWeeklyReport();
  }else if(e.parameters.view == "projects"){
    Logger.log("here view is projects");
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("project-list").evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }else if(e.parameters.view=="addproject"){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("add-project").evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }else{
    //return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("demo").evaluate();
    return HtmlService.createTemplate("<h2>demo</h2>").evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }

}
```

> about the codes:

```
setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

1. If i didn't use this, it couldnt even last until 2)step, straight away nothing after clicking Enter.
2. After adding this, it survived until the 2nd click ...

> about the Access rights:

1. it is published as latest version web app
2. published as "ME" in order to gain the most access . although i have exhausted all other options and nothing seemed to work
3. "anyone even anonymous can access app"

Comment: Your html? Browser console errors?

Comment: huh? not sure i understand your question..

Comment: Your "home.html" file?

Comment: Set base as _top

Comment: the home.html- is acting fine, the problem is when view=weekly in button "add weekly report"

Comment: let me try _top

Comment: God!! stupid me. it works miracle: base _top. thanks so so much!

Comment: In your HTML files, how are you generating the URL for each link? Hard coded or do you pull it from `ScriptApp`?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working without changing the sandbox. See a demo of it here: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzeTiyAvI3qQKodHfHFXPtSP0Sy-xU6Gwpb3SoCT8GzKLCa8i5J/exec.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e)
{
  if(e.parameters.view == "two")
  {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("two").evaluate();
  }
  else if(e.parameters.view == "three")
  {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("three").evaluate();
  }
  else if(e.parameters.view)
  {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("error").evaluate();
  }
  else
  {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("one").evaluate();
  }
}
```

**one.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    one<br />
    <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?view=two">two</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**two.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    two<br />
    <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?view=three">three</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**three.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    three<br />
    <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?view=four">four</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

error.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    error
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [`base`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) target to the `top` frame. Otherwise you'll be creating a nesting frame loop because base target defaults to `_self` and you are loading  the html in a iframe.

```html
<base target="_top">
```